# Polymer: Difference between :host and ::content CSS selector

Tags: css, dom, polymer

I am trying to apply a CSS style to the local DOM of a Polymer element. Specifically, I want to apply a style only to the `<content></content>` part of the local DOM. I tried the following element definition:

```
<dom-module id="test-element">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host > ::content { font-weight: bold; }
    </style>

    <div>Local DOM 1</div>
    <content></content>
    <div>Local DOM 2</div>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

However, not only the content is styled, but the whole element including the "Local DOM N" texts. I am aware that I can use a wrapper `<div>` element around the content to constrain the styling, but I am wondering what the difference between the selector `:host` and `:host > ::content` actually is, because the latter also applies to the whole local DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#styling-distributed-children-content):

> Under shady DOM, the `<content>` tag doesn’t appear in the DOM tree. Styles are rewritten to remove the `::content` pseudo-element, **and any combinator immediately to the left of** `::content`.

This implies that **under shady DOM** there is technically no difference between `:host > ::content` and `:host >`